# MarkdownTOC in table of contents is substituting auto for newlines on update and insert

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, tableofcontents

When editing or creating markdown files inserting of updating the table of contents will substitute the word auto for new line characters between the TOC tags.  Such as:

```
<!-- TOC fromDepth:2 ToDepth:4 insertAnchor:true -->autoauto- [1. Introduction](#1-introduction)auto- [2. Section](#2-section)auto    - [2.1. Sub Section One](#21-sub-section-one)auto    - [2.2. Sub Section Two](#22-sub-section-two)auto    - [2.3. Sub Section Three](#23-sub-section-three)autoauto<!-- /TOC -->
```

I am using VS Code and MarkdownTOC.  Any suggestions on what may be going on with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is being discussed [here](https://github.com/AlanWalk/markdown-toc/issues/65)

It seems that the issue was introduced by [a change in VSCode 1.29.0](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29#_new-default-for-fileseol-auto).

## There are two workarounds for solving this:

**1. Setting `eol` back to `\n` in VSCode settings.**

[image]

**2. Manually replace all ocurrences of `auto` with `\n`** (be careful not to break your content)

[image]